# Python os.walk from current directory

Tags: python, os.walk

How can I edit this script, that it will run from the current directory. If I run the script as it is now, I get the error that it can not find the files that I have specified. My feeling is that os.walk is not searching in the subfolders of the current directory. I do not want to specify the path name, since I want to run this script in different directories. 
To sum up; please help me to change this script, that it will run from the current directory and find the files that are in the subfolders of the current directory. Thanks!

```
import os
import csv
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict


for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    d1 = {}
    with open (os.path.join(root, 'genes.gff.genespercontig.csv'), 'r') as f1:
        for line in f1:
            ta = line.split()
            d1[ta[1]] = int(ta[0])

    d2 = {}
    with open(os.path.join(root, 'hmmer.analyze.txt.result.txt'), 'r') as f2:
        for line in f2:
            tb = line.split()
            d2[tb[1]] = int(tb[0])

    d3 = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in chain(d1.items(), d2.items()):
        d3[k].append(v)

    with open(os.path.join(root, 'output_contigsvsgenes.csv'), 'w+') as fnew:
            writer = csv.writer(fnew)     
            for k,v in d3.items(): 
                writer.writerow([k] + v)
```

Comment: by "the current directory", do you mean the location of the script?

Comment: yes, I mean with the current directory the location of the script and the location of the subfolders that has to be included with os.walk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the issue is working from the current directory, I think the issue is with the way you're using `os.walk`. You should check that the files exist before you start playing with them, and I think the error might occur because the first `root` folder is the current working directory. We can rearrange it into a function though, as follows:

```
import os
import csv
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict


def get_file_values(find_files, output_name):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        if all(x in files for x in find_files):
            outputs = []
            for f in find_files:
                d = {}
                with open(os.path.join(root, f), 'r') as f1:
                    for line in f1:
                        ta = line.split()
                        d[ta[1]] = int(ta[0])
                outputs.append(d)

            d3 = defaultdict(list)
            for k, v in chain(*(d.items() for d in outputs)):
                d3[k].append(v)

            with open(os.path.join(root, output_name), 'w+') as fnew:
                writer = csv.writer(fnew)
                for k, v in d3.items():
                    writer.writerow([k] + v)

get_file_values(['genes.gff.genespercontig.csv', 'hmmer.analyze.txt.result.txt'], 'output_contigsvsgenes.csv')
```

Not having your data I have been unable to test this, though I think it should work.

**EDIT**

To get the folder included in each row of the output csv files, we can just change our call to `writer.writerow` a little, to:

```
writer.writerow([root, k] + v)
```

Thus, the first column of each csv file created contains the name of the folder the values were obtained from.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The script works, but only for the first subdirectory. How can I manage that it will go through all subdirectories?

Comment: @Grave it should work in every subdirectory too - `os.walk` will loop through every subdirectory as `root` and return the relevant `files`. Are you sure the files are identically named in all subdirectories?

Comment: @Grave try creating an artificial folder structure of your two files in a directory and the same two in a subdirectory of that directory. I think it should work.

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure that the files are identical named in all subdirectories. What do you mean by creating an artificial folder structure. I have more than 100 subdirectories, is it not possible to go over all these subdirectories with this python script?

Comment: Just used *grep* to find the output files and in 1 subdirectory, there is a large csv file, with all columns the same value. So it looks like the script stored the output in 1 file, in a random subdirectory, and overwrite the output? What I want was to store the output file for each subdirectory in each subdirectory. Or creating one file with all the output is also fine, but then I need to include the directory names, to know from which subdirectory the output is.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this. Have you copied the indentation exactly, particularly with the declaration of `outputs` indented after the `if all(...`?

Comment: Yes, I have copied the script and did not edit anything

Comment: @Grave okay, what if you copy out, say, two of the subfolders and the script into a separate directory and run the script there. What happens?

Comment: Yes, that works! So, maybe there is an corrupt file somewhere in the "old" folders. I will check that, but your script is working. Thank you so much! Since you are very handy with this stuff; is it possible to add a line to the output file with the name of the subdirectory, so that if I want to combine all files in one large table, I can see which part is from which subdirectory.

Comment: @Grave edited it into the post. If this has fixed your problem you can mark it as the answer by clicking the tick to the left of my original post

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
os.getcwd() #return the current working directory
```

so in your case the loop changes to :

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
```

In your case you might also have to check whether the file exists or not :

```
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, 'genes.gff.genespercontig.csv')):
    with open (os.path.join(root, 'genes.gff.genespercontig.csv'), 'r') as f1:
        for line in f1:
            ta = line.split()
            d1[ta[1]] = int(ta[0])
```

similarly for all other with as statements

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but when I change the script and include os.getcwd, I still get the message: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. And I am very sure that these files are in all subfolders.

Comment: where is the file expected to be ? In the current working Direcotry or a sub directory ? or it might be anywhere in the sub directory ?

Comment: the current working directory contains multiple subdirectories and all the subdirectories contain both files that the script need. So, the files are in the subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

You could use `os.getcwd()` to get the current directory (the one you're in when calling your script), but the better would be to pass the target directory as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Within a Python script there are many options allowing deep retrospection for better orientation about the environment in which the script is running. The current directory is available via

> os.getcwd()

You have in comments suggested, that the files to work on are not in the current directory but in the subdirectories. In this case adjust your script like this (move the entire block of your loop one level deeper into `for dir in dirs:` and adjust `os.path.join()` accordingly):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for dir in dirs: 
        print(os.path.join(root, dir, 'genes.gff.genespercontig.csv'))
```

Just for the fun of it, below a short overview of some other useful insights into the environment a Python script runs within:

```
import __future__    
import os, sys
print( "Executable running THIS script    : { " + sys.executable                                          + " }" )
print( "Full path file name of THIS script: { " + os.path.realpath(__file__)                              + " }" )
print( "Full path directory to THIS script: { " + os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))              + " }" )
print( "Current working directory         : { " + os.getcwd()                                             + " }" )
print( "Has THIS file started Python?     : { " + { True: "Yes", False: "No" }[(__name__ == "__main__")]  + " }" )
print( "Which Python version is running?  : { " + sys.version.replace("\n", "")                           + " }" )
print( "Which operating system is there?  : { " + sys.platform                                            + " }" )
```